# Inversion in Mathematics

Tags: inverse

In what ways are students in grades 7-12 exposed to the mathematical concept of "inverse?"  The few I've thought of are inverse operations and finding the inverse of a function.  Any others?

Comment: Operation : "fasten shoes" vs "loose shoes".

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA To build on your idea, the "shoes and socks" theorem states that if you want to take off your socks, you first have to take off your shoes. Hence $(gh)^{-1} = h^{-1}g^{-1}$ except for certain commutative operations.

Comment: Not except for certain commutative operations. Then the formula still holds. For more such examples see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1645532/definition-of-inverse-in-linear-and-abstract-algebra).

Comment: I was imprecise. I meant "which cannot be reduced except for certain commutative operations".

Comment: Inversion w.r.t. a pole in geometry is another.